# what is the use of CICD and how it saves my time while I can simply push and pull my code from github and make my code into production too easily?

Tags: github, gitlab, cicd

I'm trying to learn CICD concepts on my own, I don't understand how it helps me while I can easily push and pull my code from github and make my code into production

Answer (score 1):

`Continuous Integration` is mainly a culture than being a tool. So, you need to understand why it's necessary that every developer on a team should integrate their code with the repository are least once a day.
`Continuous Delivery` also indicates challenges and best practices of delivering high-quality software as soon as possible. So, teams that want to decrease the risk and problems of integrating features and increase the speed of delivering new features should adopt the `CI/CD` culture.

To ensure that every code added to the repository will work and integrate with other parts, you need to check. For instance, you need to make sure that the project will be built successfully, the tests will be passed, and the new changes will not break any other parts, your code will pass some required code quality checks, and so on.

After that, you have to deploy somehow/publish the version of your software. This process usually has some steps and can be done manually in small teams/projects.

Based on the first rule of `Continuous Integration`, every team member should integrate the code with the repository multiple times a day. Since the frequency of this integration is high, it's not a good idea to do this process manually. There are always chances that somebody forgets to run the operation. That's the main reason why it's necessary to have an automatic CI/CD pipeline.